# Why can't I select a radio button in this Angular Material app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have been developing an e-commerce app with Angular 14 and Angular Material.

I am working on a registration form that contains, among others, a set of radio buttons.

In the form component's Typescript file, I have:

```
import { FormService } from '../../services/form.service';

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor (
    private formService: FormService
  ) { }

  public accountTypes!: any;
  public selectedAccountType: any;
  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccountTypes();
  }
  
   public setAccountType() {
    this.selectedAccountType = this.accountTypes[0].value;
  };

  public getAccountTypes() {
    this.formService.getAccountTypes().subscribe(response => {
      this.accountTypes = response;
      if (this.accountTypes && this.accountTypes.length) {
        this.setAccountType();
      } 
    });
  }
  
}
```

In the template:

```
<mat-radio-group name="account_type" [(ngModel)]="this.selectedAccountType">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes" value="accountType.value" [checked]="accountType.checked">
        <span class="top-label">{{ accountType.label }}</span>
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

#### The problem

For a reason I was unable to understand, when I click a (radio) button, it does not stay selected.

##### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the easiest and most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mat-radio-button` and `ngModel` you don't need to handle the `checked` property. In your case it overrides it always with `false`. You can read a lot in the official [docu](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples). Here is the right way ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvkvpoddoln?file=app/radio-ng-model-example.ts)):

*HTML:*

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
```

*And code:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-ng-model-example.css'],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `value` attribute to a property binding, that is `[value]` not `value`, it is required when using `ngModel`.

`ngModel` decides what is selected by comparing the `[value]` to the `[(ngModel)]` binding.

that is the `[value]` of the `mat-radio-button` with `selectedAccountType`.

You can remove the `checked` as it does not work with `ngModel` and a default option is already being set in `setAccountType()` method.

```html
<mat-radio-group name="account_type" [(ngModel)]="this.selectedAccountType">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes" [value]="accountType.value">
    <span class="top-label">{{ accountType.label }}</span>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```